# How do i check if a function is working fine without running it in the browser In PHP(Laravel 5.6)

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here is an example function that i'm trying to run.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $tickets = Ticketit::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(1))->where('is_notified', false)->get();

        foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
            //sending mail
            $mail= $message->to('bonderi@strathmore.edu')->body('Your ticket is overdue');

        }
    })->hourly();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "How do i check if a function is working fine without running it in the browser In PHP"? Do you want to test the function before it runs in Laravel? Have you ever heard about unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out PHPUnit and testing. Maybe use Mockery for mocking objects. It is already included by default in Laravel 5.6. Everything can be found in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/testing